# Latching IO using gpiozero

Tags: rpi.gpio, remote, pigpio, gpiozero, rpio

Im working on doing some *remote* GPIO control (de)energizing relays.  When I turn a relay on, it instantly turns off.  That makes me assume that the output doesn't latch.  I tried several of the classes used to control digital IO remotely but all of them behave the same.

```
from gpiozero import OutputDevice
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory

factory = PiGPIOFactory(host='d1p-woctorelay.local')

#RD1P Relays
las_test = OutputDevice(15, pin_factory=factory)
# las = LED(5, pin_factory=factory)
# rex = LED(6, pin_factory=factory)
# ras = LED(13, pin_factory=factory)

las_test.on()
# las.on()
# rex.off()
```

Is there something I'm missing in the docs or some basic trick to latching remotely?  I came across [this SO post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120469/using-gpiozero-for-relay-device) but it doesn't seem to work the same for remote control.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about the *why* but as I built the script it started working as expected.

```
import argparse
from gpiozero import OutputDevice
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Start, stop, or start aux equipment')
parser.add_argument('func', type=str, required=False, help='Function to perform [startup, shutdown, auxstart]')

args = parser.parse_args()

factory = PiGPIOFactory(host='d1p-woctorelay.local')

#RD1P Relays
las = OutputDevice(15, pin_factory=factory)
rex = OutputDevice(6, pin_factory=factory)
ras = OutputDevice(13, pin_factory=factory)

def startup():
    print('Starting up the machine.')
    las.on()

def shutdown():
    print('Shutting down all equipment.')
    las.off()
    rex.off()
    ras.off()

def auxstart():
    print('Starting up the auxilliary equipment.')
    rex.on()
    ras.on()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func = args.func
    if func == 'startup': startup()
    elif func == 'auxstart': auxstart()
    else: shutdown()
```