# Relay module at Raspberry Pi zero II wont work as expected

Tags: relay

I have connected `VCC` in 5V pin, `GND` in gnd pin and `IN` in GPIO 26 of my Pi.
Using simple python code to control the relay

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

relay_ch = 26
GPIO.setup(relay_ch, GPIO.OUT) // this switch the relay on (green led with sound)

GPIO.output(relay_ch, GPIO.HIGH) //this wont do anything
GPIO.output(relay_ch, GPIO.LOW) //this wont do anything
GPIO.output(relay_ch, True) //this wont do anything
GPIO.output(relay_ch, False) //this wont do anything

GPIO.setup(relay_ch, GPIO.IN) // this turn the relay swift off
```

why??

I'm using SRD-05VDC-SL-C relay module.

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct pin? https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin37_gpio26

Comment: What relay module? Most won't work with a Pi. Have you checked ANY of the hundreds of similar questions?

Comment: As hinted, your 5V relay may not be triggered by the Pi's 3.3V outputs. Post a photo of your wiring and a link to the actual relay board you are using. Also modify your code to something that will trigger the relay on or off with time.sleep(2) after each.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use a 5V Relay Module with the Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/can-you-use-a-5v-relay-module-with-the-pi)