How to send 5v signal from pi?
I am using a raspberry pi 4b. I am attepting to send a signal to a motor controller that requires a 5v input. Is that possible with the pi or will i need to purchase a part. If so please advise an recommendations. The part is DM8078 made by microkinetics
link to driver documentation

Logic level converter can be an option.

The data sheet lies! It claims to need TTL input @30mA. It also claims to be open collector compatible. No TTL source is capable of this. Real TTL is current driven, capable of sinking current but only sourcing limited current.
I suspect it actually has opto-isolators as input.
These can be driven with a simple transistor circuit (but you would need to conform this). See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118117/8697 for examples.
